# Saving selected item in radio button forms as integer using Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I am building a website with forms using Angular on frontend and Rails on backend. When user selects an item in radiobutton questions, I would like to save an answer for the selected item as integer not string. My code for this currently saves an answer as string.

Code for radio button question view:

```
<div class="content-block vertical-offset--small">
    <label class="radio-control" ng-repeat="value in field.values" style="display:block;">
          <input type="radio" id="{{field.id}}" name="field.id"
                 ng-model="formData[field.id]"
                 value="value.id" ng-blur="realtimeSave()">{{value.title}}
           <div class="control-indicator"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Data I'm using:

```
{
"field": {
        "id": "2_4_requested_action",
        "title": "4. Requested Action",
        "type": "radio",
        "validations": {
                "required": true,
                "min_length": 2
        },
        "size": {
                "width": 100,
                "height": 2
        },
        "values": [
                {
                        "id": 0,
                        "title": "a"
                },
                {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "b"
                },
                {
                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "c"
                },
                {
                        "id": 3,
                        "title": "d"
                }
        ]
}
}
```

If I select the first item, it saves the answer as {"2_4_requested_action":"0"}. I want to save the answer in integer like following: {"2_4_requested_action":0}.

I know I need to do something with "value" attribute in input but I'm not 100% sure what I should do.

Comment: Could you provide more code samples (at least the logic for realtimeSave), and even better than that a demo?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

You could `parseFloat` or `parseInt` the string before you save it into your object.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm

Comment: I tried  `value="{{parseInt(value.id, 10)}}"` and it saves the answer as `"parseInt(0, 10)"`. Wasn't working.